How to compare 2 pdfs and return true/false if they are the same (have same content) without using any pdf library?
How can I write a c# method to take 2 pdf filenames and return true if their content is identical, false otherwise. I am not concerned with what the differences are.
What I have tried:

Comparing the 2 files as binary.


public static bool PdfFilesHaveTheSameContent(string filePathOne, string filePathTwo)
       {
           var file1 = File.ReadAllBytes(filePathOne);
           var file2 = File.ReadAllBytes(filePathTwo);

           if (file1.Length != file2.Length)
               return false;

           for (var i = 0; i < file1.Length; i++)
           {
               if (file1[i] != file2[i])
               {
                   return false;
               }
           }

           return true;
       }

I have also tried a similar method reading the text (with File.ReadAllText())
I assume the above method/s don't work as there are some meta data being stored with the pdf like a guid or date modified or something. Is it possible to remove this? I have tried opening the pdf in a text editor but it is gibberish and may need decoding somehow.
Everything I've seen online recommends just using one of the many pdf libraries, unfortunately this isn't an option for me. It needs to be done in core .Net only.
Is this possible?

the easiest way would be to get a hash from both files and see if they are the same. But that would only tell you if the two are exactly the same file

So you want to ignore the differences in metadata? That can become a slippery slope. What else do you want to ignore?

You can't just compare the contents. PDFs aren't documents with text, they're files containing printing commands, more specifically Postscript. The same print output can be generated by different Postscript commands or sequence of commands. It doesn't matter where you put 72 500 moveto in a file, it will still move printing to the same point.

You would need to parse the file if you want to do a more intelligent comparison. But what do you consider "content"? Do you care about layout? metadata? Whitespace? Even just comparing strings can be rather complicated, see collations

Why it needs to be done without any library?

I basically need to confirm that if both the pdfs were images, would they look the same?

Why are people voting to close this? Can I have a reason. is it not a valid question?

If you need to compare if the files would look the same to a human you will have quite some work in front of you. You would need to do something like rendering the files and use image comparison techniques. Not impossible, but very costly. And you should likely reconsider the problem to find some better approach.

"Do they look the same?" is not a question that will elicit objective answers. How do you define "looks the same"? If some text is in a slightly different position, but is otherwise identical, does that "look the same"?

So a pdf containing the same plaintext but just in a different font should be non equal?

In a comment you clarified

I basically need to confirm that if both the pdfs were images, would they look the same?

To check that you unfortunately have to render the PDFs as images. And to render the PDFs as images, quite some code is needed. So in combination with your remark

Everything I've seen online recommends just using one of the many pdf libraries, unfortunately this isn't an option for me. It needs to be done in core .Net only.

this means that will have have to add the code equivalent of one of such PDF libraries to your project, at least until core .NET starts offering PDF rendering APIs.

As an aside: already "as images looking the same" is more complicated than you may think: PDF may look different if rendered on different devices, e.g. two PDFs may look identical on an RGB screen but as a CMYK (probably plus spot colors etc.) print-out they may look really different.
